# express and events with winston logger set up halts logging to file on error occurrence

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, winston

I am using [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) with my [express](https://expressjs.com/) application with [events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html). Logger has two transporters for writing to file and console.

Logger is working fine except when there is some error occurrence. 
On error, Winston keeps writing to the console but does not write to the file.

Expected behavior is that winston should write to file also on even error occurrence.

What is wrong with my `express + winston + events` setup?

Here is my setup

```js
const winston = require('winston');
const express = require('express')
var events = require('events');

async function handleDoSomethingHeavy(payload) {
  console.log('alok', payload)
  throw new Error('Something went wrong')
}

var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
eventEmitter.on('doSomethingHeavy', (payload) => {
  setImmediate(handleDoSomethingHeavy, payload)
});

const app = express()
const port = 3000

var options = {
  file: {
    level: 'debug',
    filename: `mylogs-${Date.now()}.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.splat(),
      winston.format.timestamp(),
    ),
    maxsize: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
    maxFiles: 10,
  },
  console: {
    level: 'debug',
    handleExceptions: true,
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.splat(),
      winston.format.timestamp(),
    ),
  }
}

var logger = winston.createLogger({
  levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.file),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
  ],
  exitOnError: false,
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  logger.info('Got get request')
  let payload = { name: 'Alok' }
  eventEmitter.emit('doSomethingHeavy', payload);
  res.send('Task queued')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  // console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
  logger.info(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Can you provide an example where errors aren't being logged to file?

Comment: example code is in question itself.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see. It seems to work fine for the first request, but not any subsequent requests.

Comment: In my case I see all logs in console even on errors. But in cse of file logging does not appear in log file when error occurs. e.g. `handleDoSomethingHeavy(payload)`

Comment: For me, the first error that gets caught is logged both to console and to the file. Subsequent errors are only logged to console. Not sure why.

Comment: yes after error occurance logs are written to only console.

Comment: This feels like a bug in Winston, but I can't find anything about it on its Github page.

Comment: yes, Thanks for trying my code and replying :)